# Tensor to numpy conversion without gradient dependence

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am creating a custom loss function to use with Keras in a CNN-architecture for segmentation. The loss should be a binary-cross-entropy-loss with each pixel weighted by the distance to the boundary of the GT foreground. 
This distance is easily calculated with the scipy function `scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt`, but this functions requires a numpy-array as an input. For the loss function I only have "y_true" and "y_pred" which are both tensors.

I have tried converting "y_true" to a numpy array using `np_y_true = y_true.eval()`, but get the following error:
('conv3d_19_target' is the name for the placeholder of y_true. The shape of this is unknown to the program at this stage, though it is always (1,64,64,64,2).

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'conv3d_19_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?,?,?,?]

I have also tried `np_y_true = y_true.numpy()`, with the following result:

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

I believe there is two issues:

1. y_true is just a placeholder, and is therefore unknown when the loss function is first read.
2. Keras/tensorflow believes that the gradient should pass through all parts that are dependent on y_true. This is however not
   necessary here, as this is just a weight parameter to be calculated
   at each pass.

A first attempt on how I thought of my loss function:

```py
def DFweighted_entropy(): 
    def weighted_loss(y_true,y_pred):
        np_ytrue = y_true.numpy() #OR 
        #np_y_true = K.eval(y_true)

        #Calculate distance-field:
        df_inside = distance_transform_edt(np_ytrue[:,:,:,1]) #Background
        df_outside = distance_transform_edt(np_ytrue[:,:,:,0]) #Foreground
        np_df = np_ytrue[:,:,:,1]*df_inside+np_ytrue[:,:,:,0]*df_outside #Combined

        #Loss: 
        df_loss = (K.max(y_pred,0)-y_pred * y_true + K.log(1+K.exp((-1)*K.abs(y_pred))))*np_df
        return df_loss

    return weighted_loss
```

The loss function is used when the model is compiled:

`model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-4,beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08,decay=0.0),loss = DFweighted_entropy(), metrics=['acc',dice_coefficient])`

Any ideas for solutions are appreciated!